# How to get examples data of scenario outline in Cucumber listener

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

There is a test automation java project that works with tests written in BDD style. There is a cucumber listener which is used to extract information about tags, like this:

```
public final class E2EPlugin implements ConcurrentEventListener {

    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseStarted.class, this::testStarted);
    }

    public void testStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
        List<String> tags = event.getTestCase().getTags();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Now we need to extend it and get information about the dataset of example that being used for the run. So I need to distinguish Scenario and Scenario Outline and in case of outline get the data of the current example.